# Pickerview populated by array of strings adding to new array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

Sorry to kind of be vague in the question. I currently have a pickerView populated by an array of strings. The string is set by this function...

```
_homePlayer = _homePlayersArray[indexPath.row];

            // add to the copy
            [_homeConfirmedPlayersArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@ %@",_homePlayer.number,_homePlayer.firstName,_homePlayer.lastName]];
```

I have it populate the pickerView which works properly. I now want to be able to pick from the picker and take just the first part of the string and set it as an NSString. Is this possible and if so how would i go about doing this? Could i change some things to be able to accomplish this? thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, very vague. Please clarify. What have you tried so far? What does the posted code have to do with the question or a picker view?

Comment: This code has to do with the picker view cause it is the array that i use to populate the view. I want to be able to choose from the view which will display up to 20 of these strings each with a different name and number. I want to be able to take just the number from the chosen string instead of the whole string. Any other information that you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the delegate for your UIPickerView

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    Player *player = _homePlayersArray[row];
    NSInteger number = player.number;
}
```

Comment: how would i be able to use that with a picker view? would i be able to make it do that only for the one that is chosen in the view?

Comment: Set some object as the delegate for the UIPickerView. That object will be called when you select a row from the picker view. Then using the code from above, you will be able to find the first component of the string the user selected from the picker view.